# Convert query from SQL to cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have a SQL query like:

```
SELECT a,b,c
from 'table '
where a like '$ae%' and b = '$b'.
```

Here `$a` is a numeric field.
I need to write the above query in below form:

```
$abc = ClassRegistry::init('Model Name')->find('list', array('fields' => array('a,', 'b'), 'conditions' => array('b' => array($b),'a LIKE'=>'$a%'),));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go and read the  documentation.

Also remember to always cite the exact cake version, and if you have some error, show that error in your question.

Anyway, since you did show some kind of effort, here the way to do that query using cake3:

first of all don't use find('list') unless you actually want a key, value array. But since you want 3 fields use `find('all')` or simply `find()`

```
$query = $yourTable->find()
    ->select(['a', 'b', 'c')
    ->where([
        'b' => $b,
        'a LIKE' =>"%$a%"
    ]);
```

then if you want an array you have to call `toArray()` on the query.

```
$result = $query->toArray();
```

Comment: Hi @prajakta if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. If you are still getting some error consider editing you question adding more information